# PHP wildcard reverse proxy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am not sure what to call this, but I will try to describe my question/theory as best I can:

I have a development server that lies at `dev.domain.com` with a wildcard `*.dev.domain.com`.  My desire is to set up an Virtual Host for `*.dev.domain.com` what points to a directory with a `.htaccess` file that directs all requests to a single php file.  That PHP file would then determine if `(.+).dev.domain.com` points to a directory available in some directory.

I'm...  Not sure how to accomplish this.

At it's most basic, it could search in a folder for other folders that are symlinked there.  Or, more complicated: it could look a few other places.

The end-goal is to be able to clone a repo into a new folder, make an edit, and sent a link for testing, all without changing DNS, or Apache settings.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a better way?